# Inverse discrete time Fourier transform with differentiation

Tags: fourier-transform, homework, self-study, dtft

Consider a signal x[n] and its DTFT $X(e^{jω})$ . Assume $X(e^{jω})$ is differentiable. Compute the inverse DTFT of

$j\frac{dX(e^{jω})}{d\omega}$

You should write your answer in terms of $x[n]$ and elementary functions and constants, for example $π/2x[n]$ would be written :

$\pi / 2x[n]$

Comment: What have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

differentiate from Fourier Transform equation:

$$X(e^{j\omega})= \sum\limits_{n=- \infty }^{\infty}x[n]e^{-jn\omega} \Rightarrow \frac{d}{d\omega}X(e^{j\omega})= \frac{d}{d\omega}\sum\limits_{n=- \infty }^{\infty}x[n]e^{-jn\omega}$$

and then find what you want.